# How can I change the color of a Bootstrap 3 glyphicon to white if it's not included in the glyphicon package?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Our project has the Bootstrap 3 glyphicons included in it. However, the glyphicon download package doesn't have the unlock glyphicon. You have to download that one separately and include it by itself. because of this, i'm having a hard time getting it to act like the other glyphicons.

below is the library files where the package of glyphicons are stored and the /public/img  folder where i have the unlock glyphicon.

[image: Where my normal glyphicons are stored, in a library]

[image: where i have added the glyphicons-unlock.png file]

I've tried everything i can think of to turn this icon white.

```html
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li>
        <a id="unlock-all" href="#" title="Unlock All" >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicons-unlock icon-white" style="color:white;" >
             <img src="/public/img/glyphicons-unlock.png" > 
         </span>   
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

in my css:

```html
#unlock-all {
  color: #ffffff;

}

.glyphicon.glyphicons-unlock.white {
  color: #ffffff;
}


#unlock-all .glyphicon {
  color: #ffffff;

}
```

does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? And yes, i know there is another stackoverflow asking this similar question but it does NOT address this specifically and its solution does not work for me.

EDIT: ANSWERED:

used this solution:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

     <li>
        <a id="unlock-all" href="#" title="Unlock All" >
        <i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #ffffff; background-color:black;"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
```

and i actually changed the color in css but couldn't figure out how to do that in this "insert code" option. ie:

```
#unlock-all {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You do realise you're trying to pull in a .png right? CSS can't change colors of image.s

Comment: Yeah, i thought we were doing that in other parts of our code but i think they were being used differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have said, you can't alter the colour of an image with css.

I'd be inclined to switch from the glyphicons to  the (awsome) fontawsome which you can find here: http://fontawesome.io

It works in much the same way as the glyphicon set and has many more icons for free.

This should do what you want once you have included the fontawsone file, which is also available on CDNs as well as direct download:

```
<i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>
```

As a bonus, as well as being ale to set the colourwith css, there are also  classes to  get different sizes: http://fontawesome.io/icon/unlock/

Hope this helps

Comment: @andy I don;t have the rep to comment on your answer. That's clever! (I think I'd still go with font-awesome though <grin>)

Comment: i was trying to avoid bringing in another set of images, but i was able to get this to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property and a bit of trickery:

```css
img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- This image is naturally black -->
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/k66su2k.png">
```

We set the image's brightness to 0 making it black, then invert it which makes it white.

Comment: i can see this works in your example but i couldn't get it to stop whiting out my entire image! cool hack though :) i ended up using the other answer someone posted. thank you for commenting though!

Comment: @user2847749 That's cool, it's probably better to use font awesome instead of this little hack. If it were me I'd get rid of glyphicons altogether and replace them all with the font awesome icons.